# Regarding maxIndexingThreads config in solrconfig.xml

Tags: multithreading, solr, lucene

I have a solr cluster with 8 server(4 shards with one replica for each). I
have 80 client threads indexing to this cluster. Client is running on a
different machine. I am trying to figure out optimal number of indexing
threads.

Now, solrconfig.xml have a config for *maxIndexingThreads*:

"The maximum number of simultaneous threads that may be indexing documents
at once in IndexWriter; if more than this many threads arrive they will wait
for others to finish. Default in Solr/Lucene is 8. "

I want to know whether this configuration is per solr instance or per
core(or collection).

Also is there a way to specify number of threads used by queries?

Comment: For others finding this question, it is also [discussed in Solr's mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg93359.html). Probably there are answers then.

Comment: Extra note: maxIndexingThreads is now removed from Lucene/Solr: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6659